# Adding weekly column and last week's number then to make overall cumulative column in excel

Tags: excel, function, sum

I have a three columns

1. Weekly result
2. Result from last week
3. Cumulative result.

I want to add all of them to get total value in cumulative.

[image]

Help me pls

Comment: it's difficult to picture what you're trying to do.  Can you show this graphically somehow?  are you simply trying to sum the values in A1 and B1 and put the result in C1?  Or do you want to sum all values in column A and all values in column B and put the result in C1?

Comment: I ve placed an image, just click in "enter image description here"

Comment: can you show us a snapshot on how the answer might look like?

Comment: Guys okey, lets solve first problem only: For now i just want to add 1 column "Week rotation hours" to Cumulative column, so everytime i insert numbers in 1st column it will make cumulative total hours only

Answer (score 0):

Excel sum function takes a range and adds all of the values in that range.

if you want to sum A1 and B1 and put the result in C1 then enter =SUM(A1:B1) in cell C1.

if you want to sum everything in, for instance A1 to A50 and B1 to B50 you would enter =sum(A1:B50) in cell C1.

There's also a shortcut for the sum function in Excel.  If you go to cell C2 and hit ALT and the =/+ button it will suggest cells to SUM.  It will insert the SUM function for you.

One more thing - you don't need to insert the function in every cell.  Just insert the function in one cell and then double click the bottom-right corner of the cell with the function and it will copy the function down to cells below it.

Comment: Neal, probably my question was unclear. What you told me is pretty simple, thanks anyway. I have two columns with "Weekly rotation in hours" one for current week and another for previous week. and then i have a column which will be total or cumulative rotation in hours; it can be in a year or so. What i want is when i add number in current week it will be summing to cumulative, but when the week will be passed i want this hours as well to be summed in previous week column

Comment: I guess I'm unsure of what you're asking.  I assume you're looking for some type of automation using VBA to update sums at the end of each week.

Comment: Thank you Neal, i believe there is way to do it without VBA, just add the result from week to cumulative.